# Strapi global filter for all "findMany" queries

Tags: strapi

I need a global filter for the model in the Strapi.

```
const companies = await strapi.entityService.findMany('api::company.company',{
  filters: { ...variousFiltersParameters },
  ...otherParameters
})
```

But in all these places I need a single use filters: `{ deleted: false }`, simulating soft-delete.

This option does not suit me

```
export default createCoreController('api::company.company', ({strapi}) => ({
  async find(ctx){
    // ...code
  }
}) )
```

Because "findMany" I use in different parts of the code (custom controllers, custom resolvers)

Is there a universal way with use policy or middleware?